# Setting the Root View Controller of a UIWindow

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have started a xCode 3 project using the "Create a Window-Based Application" option.  Everything seems to be ok and quite a lot has been done.  But then it comes to a stage where I wish to add a flip transition to another view.  And the related documentations seem to suggest that I need a rootViewController for my UIWindow to do flip views.  (The project has been moved to xCode 4.2)

My questions is :

Is there a safe and efficient way to add a rootViewController after the project has been started for some time ?

Also have tried the following code :

```
- (void) setup_root_view_controller

{

root_view_controller = [[UIViewController alloc] 
                       initWithNibName : nil 
                       bundle          : nil ];

[root_view_controller setView : [[window subviews] objectAtIndex : 0]]; 

[window setRootViewController : root_view_controller];     

}
```

The above code compiles and runs ok except that the following "about_screen" doesn't show.

```
about_screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[root_view_controller presentModalViewController : about_screen animated : YES];
```

Comment: "Everything seems to be ok and quite a lot has been done." - Does this mean that majority of what is accomplished in your application is just the standard template code?  If not much code has been written, is it possible to just start over using the xcode 4.2 utility template?  This provides all the code needed to do a view flip.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  There has been several months of work.  Just hope that I could avoid having to start nearly all over again ...

Answer (score 1):

`rootViewController` is a property of `UIWindow`. That template should have provided you with a MainWindow.xib file which you can open in Interface Builder (since we're talking Xcode 3).  You can use right-click and drag from the `rootViewController` outlet of the `UIWindow` to the appropriate `UIViewController` you've added to the XIB in Interface Builder.

If you want to do it programmatically, that template should have also setup a `window` property in your `AppDelegate`.  You can use that property to assign `rootViewController` to a `UIViewController` you instantiate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Will give it a try on 4.2 as I don't have any 3.x backups anymore.